# What does it mean "to have runs of sth"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading an article about data compression in computer when i faced this sentence:

> It tends to be easy to compress a string that has runs of repeated
>   characters by techniques such as move-to-front transform and
>   run-length encoding.

I know this is about computers but i don't think that the part "having runs of" is about computers. So, What does it mean?

I also appreciate if you give some examples of using it. I searched by didn't find anything!  The sentence itself was found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform).

Comment: "It tends to be easy to compress a string that has "[a continuous series](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+run+of)" of repeated characters by techniques..." (The Free Dictionary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "run" is a sequence where the same character or pattern repeats. For example, "111111111" is a run of ones.  "ABCABCABCABC" is a run of "ABC"

You can compress those by methods such as listing the character or pattern, and then a count of how many times it repeats, which takes less space than repeating the character or pattern and doesn't lose any of the information.